# Use ajax request to get php data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function

Hey all im trying to use ajax to get a php file and run a few functions.

My ajax looks like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".claim-button").click(function(){
        alert("click ok");
        var baseUrl = document.location.origin;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/custom_functions/win_checker.php'
        });
    });
});
```

Then in the php file I put something simple jsut to test it works:

```
echo "Test";
```

I get the jquery "click ok" but it does not return the php echo.

Im am very new to ajax could someone please advise what im doing wrong.

Many thanks

David

Comment: Check the console for error

Comment: you must add 'success' function for get response in ajax function

Comment: _“but it does not return the php echo”_ - no, _you_ are not doing anything with the response. Go read up on how to use jQuery.ajax, and how you deal with the server’s response.

Comment: Show your form too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `success` to capture the PHP response:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".claim-button").click(function(){
        alert("click ok");
        var baseUrl = document.location.origin;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/custom_functions/win_checker.php',
            data: {var1: 'someValue'},
            success: function(response){
                alert(response); // this will alert 'Test'
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In PHP, you will get parameters in `$_POST`.

Comment: MAny thanks but what about if you want to pass data the otehr way for instance when sending the ajax to the php page send over a string or a variable, how do you send this and then how do you get this with the php please

Comment: Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

To handle the output of the AJAX request, you have to provide a function to be executed on success:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".claim-button").click(function(){
        alert("click ok");
        var baseUrl = document.location.origin;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/custom_functions/win_checker.php',
            success: function(result) {
            // Do with your result what you want, e.g. print it to the console
              console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```